# Powershell - Move files in different folders every hour

Tags: powershell

Trying to move images from one folder into another folder but this needs to be scheduled every hour moving a chunk at a time, I've got the images chunked into folders with 1000 images in each folder.

Folder structure;

```
tobemoved\1
tobemoved\2
tobemoved\3
tobemoved\4

[etc.. up to 66]
```

These files are being moved into a single folder on the network `\\images\web\upload`

Is it possible to achieve this with a Powershell script, or any suggestions of an easy way to do this?

Comment: Well yes, it is very easily done with PowerShell. Have you tried anything? You could very simply chuck each of these folders into an array and loop through the array with a Start-Sleep -s 3600 between each loop.

Comment: I wouldn't use `Start-Sleep` as this would mean you have a single long-running with little options to recover if it hangs or fails. Instead use Task Scheduler as it's purpose built to run tasks on a schedule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use Sleep as mentioned in the comments, this would mean you have a single long-running script with minimal option to recover from failure. If the script crashes, no more copy actions happen until it's re-launched.

instead, use Task Scheduler to run the script every hour. It's purpose built to run tasks on a schedule and has options to deal with failure and re-running.

Each task is run in its own process, so if the previous task fails it doesn't affect the next task - which still runs as normal.

---

No need to batch the images into folders, you can use `Select-Object` to do this for you.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\folder\source -File -Recurse | Select-Object -First 1000 | Move-Item -Destination \\images\web\upload -WhatIf
```

This will select the first 1000 files by name and path:

```
C:\folder\source\imageA.jpg
C:\folder\source\imageB.jpg
C:\folder\source\folderA\imageF.jpg
C:\folder\source\folderA\imageE.jpg
C:\folder\source\folderB\imageD.jpg
C:\folder\source\folderC\imageC.jpg
```

And move them all into the folder `\\images\web\upload`:

```
\\images\web\upload\imageA.jpg
\\images\web\upload\imageB.jpg
\\images\web\upload\imageC.jpg
\\images\web\upload\imageD.jpg
[etc]
```

Note: This assumes you're using a modern version of Powershell as the `-File` param isn't available in earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer however, I'm getting the below error; any idea why?
Move-Item: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At C:\Users\yash\Desktop\File-Move.ps1:1 char:70
+ First 1000 | Move-Item -Destination \\server\images\Web\.
+ CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (image1.jpg:PSObject) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand